# Scala: how to reference class properties from nested class

Tags: scala, class

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyProg(prop: Int) {
  var K = prop

  def myFunc() {
    class UtilityClass() {
      //does stuff that uses K
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to have `UtilityClass` access the K parameter without (1) explicitly passing K, and (2) without allowing MyProg.K value to be mutated by operations inside of `UtilityClass`.

E.g. I have tried:

```
class MyProg(prop: Int) {
  var K = prop

  def myFunc() {
    class UtilityClass() {
      K = MyProg.this.K
      //does stuff that uses K
    }
  }
}
```

But this (1) seems to operate as a pass by reference, and anything done in the utility class to K now changes the MyProg.K value, and (2) `MyProg.this.K` syntax doesn't make any sense.

What is the correct way for UtilityClass to access K? How the heck does `MyProg.this.K` mean anything?

Comment: just don't use `var`s, they are evil anyway. Make `K` a `val`,  and use it in the nested class as just `K`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course if you use a val instead of a var, your problem is solved, right?

So I assume, that you need to have the field as a mutable variable in your class.

You can prevent outside manipulation of the variable by using the access modifier `private`, and define use a public getter, so other classes can access it's value:

```
 class MyProg(prop: Int) {
  private var _K = prop
  def K = _K
}

val peekAtK = new MyProg(4).K           
//> peekAtK  : Int = 4
```

The private modifier prohibits all other classes from accessing the variable, however, a nested class exists in the same lexical scope, and it will always be able to access the field K.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
K = MyProg.this.K
```

This does not do anything, it just re-assigns `K` to itself. All references to `K` inside `UtilityClass` are references to `K` in `MyProg`. So when you update `K` in `UtilityClass` you change the value of `K` in `MyProg`.

I think you want this:

```
var K = MyProg.this.K
```

Now there is a new `K` in `UtilityClass` which can be updated without affecting the `K` in `MyProg`. By using the same name you hide the outer `K` from the rest of `UtilityClass` and protect it from being changed.

Of course the warnings about using `var` also apply, so look for a way to make `K` a `val` if possible. If `K` is a `val` then you can just use it in `UtilityClass` directly.